# 500 Internal Server Error & AADSTS54005 Error after installing & starting the Eclipse Che IDE on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, refresh-token, eclipse-che

I installed Eclipse Che on Azure by following the instructions under https://eclipse.dev/che/docs/stable/administration-guide/installing-che-on-microsoft-azure/
and expected that I shall be able to start/login to the the IDE.

Did anybody recently manage to install Eclipse Che on Azure by following the instructions under https://eclipse.dev/che/docs/stable/administration-guide/installing-che-on-microsoft-azure/?

I desperately try to do this, but after completing the steps I receive in my browser the error message

500 Internal Server Error

(and in the log file of oauth2 I receive the error
“'AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code, or use an existing refresh token.
Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: could not get claim 'email': failed to fetch claims from profile URL: error making request to profile URL: unexpected status '401')

when I submit the command chectl dashboard:open in order to start the IDE.

I consulted Microsoft and they say the following:

"This behavior is to be expected when your application reuses authorization codes to get tokens. I would recommend you to revisit your code and see if your application reuses code. If your app reuses authorization codes to get tokens for multiple resources, we recommend that you use the code to get a refresh token, and then use that refresh token to acquire additional tokens for other resources.
Authorization codes can only be used once but refresh tokens can be used multiple times across multiple resources. Any new app that attempts to reuse an authentication code during the OAuth code flow will get an invalid_grant error AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed."

So I would like to discuss with somebody the following issues:

a) how I can get Eclipse Che to behave as recommended by Microsoft
b) if I did something wrong while executing the instructions of the above web page
c) if maybe Eclipse Che is not functioning on Azure Cloud at all

Thank you in advance